# Constant "<Untitled> Download unsuccessful." notifications

Tags: notifications, troubleshooting, download-manager, zte-blade

I'm constantly harassed by these *"<Untitled> Download unsuccessful."* notifications.

[image: <Untitled> Download unsuccessful.]

After taking the above screenshot, I cleared the entire notifications list. Within the next three minutes (usually even less), the list was already overflowing again.

[image: <Untitled> Download unsuccessful.]

I've learned to manage the symptom by navigating to the ***Download Manager*** application settings; hitting *FORCE STOP*, followed by *CLEAR DATA*, and *CLEAR CACHE*. Although the notifications slowly start showing up again. Just one at first, but gradually increasing in number with each occurance. Within a day or two, the numbers are usually back out of control.

[image: Download Manager application settings]
[image: Download Manager application settings]

I have no idea what it's supposedly attempting to download, or why. But whatever it is, it's not instigated by myself. I could just disable download notifications, but I'd rather identify the underlying problem and kill it directly. Needless to say, I'm not too keen on my devices automatically trying to download random mystery files from the internet. Any ideas? Thanks.

FYI: The device in question is a **ZTE Blade L5** smartphone.

Comment: Possible way to find the culprit – please verify: From the app drawer, open the app "Downloads". It should list all downloads and, in a separate column, give the package name of the app having requested it.

Comment: @Izzy I checked. It just says *No items*. Which is weird. I've downloaded a few things; like `.jpeg`s, `.pdf`s, etc. I doubt it's malware. It's been doing this since day one.

Comment: That's really strange. If you long press such a notification and then tap the ⓘ icon, what app does that link to? Side note: malware can also come preinstalled – though I agree that in this case this is unlikely (too obvious with those notifications).

Comment: @Izzy *Download Manager*.

Comment: That's strange – then the files should be listed in the place I've mentioned. If the downloader purges them from there, that sounds rather malicious (or at least suspect). But AFAIK only system apps can do that via the [`ACCESS_DOWNLOAD_MANAGER_ADVANCED`](https://android.izzysoft.de/catmin/applists/perms#ACCESS_DOWNLOAD_MANAGER_ADVANCED) permission.

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved my issue with constant "download unsuccessful" notifications. In the Puffin browser I went to settings and the download icon then erased all. Haven't seen an instance for quite awhile.

Answer (score -1):

I found out what it was with es file explorer. On home, where it says recent downloaded files it will say what files around how long ago.  Subtract those with the time current time and you've got your culprit. I hope this lasts. It was text now from panda helper

Answer (score -2):

I have had this problem with the ZTE BLADE and found that if you go into *Settings › Notifications › Downloads,* then block the Downloads, it should stop the notifications after you clear them a couple of times. It worked for me.

Comment: "I could just disable download notifications, but I'd rather identify the underlying problem and kill it directly." Like the OP, I think hiding the fact that some malware on your phone trying to download files continually is not a good response to the situation.